# Can I use this MOSFET instead of the standard FS8205?

Tags: mosfet, lipo

In my current circuit, I have the FS8205 MOSFET in combination with a DW01A for lithium battery protection, but the MOSFET is out of stock.  I found another MOSFET labeled "FS8205A". Can I just switch them out?

[image]

Description of FS8205 (current one)

- 20V 6A 28mΩ@4.5V,4A 1W 1.2V@250uA 2 N-Channel SOT-23-6
- [Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810110910_Fortune-Semicon-FS8205_C32254.pdf)

Description of the new FS8205A

- 20V 6A 19.5mΩ@4.5V,3A 1.5W 700mV@250uA 58pF@10V 2 N-Channel 466pF@10V 5.7nC@10V -55℃~+150℃@(Tj) SOT-23-6
- [Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2108132230_TECH-PUBLIC-FS8205A_C2830320.pdf)

I see that they have different resistance values but I don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the A suffix is “equivalent or better” with a lower resistance and thus would operate cooler.  All other critical parameters are insensitive to the function as an almost ideal diode switch.